# Does standard "Settings" layout for ListView items exist?(+)

Tags: android

I need to implement Settings Layout for my application.
Generally this should be ListView with items that are looks same as in other preinstalled applicatons' Settings Menus.

For example in Gallery->Press "Menu" button->Setting there is menu item "Display Size" with two rows of Text (title and description) and Image (down arrow) at the right.

I know that I can create own layout for such items and populate my ListView with SimpleAdapter, but I'm not sure if this correct solution if I need to provide same look and feel as in preinstalled applications. I wonder maybe there is some standard layout or maybe even different approaches for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forsaken,

It seems like you mean to use a [`PreferenceScreen`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceScreen.html).  Here is a good tutorial on how to use these: http://www.kaloer.com/android-preferences